# I can not able to create deleted fields again with same api name on object

Tags: custom-field, administration

I have an object called creditBook and I deleted certain fields from this object let us say (Amount Used) with API name Amount_Used__c.

I just also deleted this field from deleted history field.Now again I want that same fields but its throwing an error saying that "There is already a field named Amount_Used on Credit Book."

Yes obviously I can change the API name by keeping the field name as same but thats not a feasible solution.

Comment: Did you check in the recycle bin?

Comment: Are you working on a managed package ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the key question to ask is whether your object and field are in a managed package. You can delete them, but Salesforce will not allow you to recreate them with the same name. The reason for this is that when you delete the field from your package, and your customer upgrades the package, it will remain as an *unamanged* field in his org. He can choose whether to delete it or not.

Reference: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_managed_component_deletion.htm

Note this:

> Also, once you delete a component in a managed package, you can’t restore it or create another component with the same name.
>   Of course, none of this is applicable if your field is not packaged.

Answer (score 1):

There is link under custom fields named "**Deleted Fields (X)**". you need to clink on this link and then erase the field to delete permanently.

If you don't see this link then there are are only 2 reasons for it:

1) There must be some confusion. Check the object definition again and make sure you do not have field "**Amount_Used__c**". Hint use CTRL+F to find test in browser.

2) There must be error in salesforce and metadata sync process. If you are 100% sure that the field is not there and still its throwing error then you need to raise case with salesforce. But I am 99.99 % sure that its not issue with salesforce.

Comment: I already permanently deleted  all the fields from **Deleted Fields (X)** and again verified in objects its I could not found any field like **Amount_Used__c__**

Comment: As Atul suggested, wait for sometime. If it still doesn't resolves the issue, raise a case with Salesforce.